# i am need of trigger handler hitting limit of SOQL queries

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code, apex

```
Trigger UpdateActivityCountonAccountContactOptyevent on Event (after insert, after delete){
    map<id,integer>mopportunityCount = new map <id,integer>();
    map<id,integer>maccountCount = new map <id,integer>();
    map<id,integer>mcontactCount = new map<id,integer>();
    Integer OptyCount = 0;
    Integer AccountCount = 0;
    Integer ContactCount = 0;
    if(trigger.isinsert){
        for(event e: trigger.new){
            if(e.whoId != null){
                if(string.valueOf(e.WhoId).left(3) == '003'){
                    if(mcontactCount.containsKey(e.WhoId)){
                        ContactCount = mcontactCount.get(e.WhoId);
                    }
                    ContactCount = ContactCount + 1;
                    mcontactCount.put(e.whoid,ContactCount);
                }
            }
            if(e.whatId != null){
                if(string.valueOf(e.WhatId).left(3) == '006'){
                    if(mopportunityCount.containsKey(e.WhatId)){
                        OptyCount = mopportunityCount.get(e.WhatId);
                    }
                    OptyCount = OptyCount + 1;
                    mopportunityCount.put(e.whatid,OptyCount);
                }
                if(string.valueOf(e.WhatId).left(3) == '001'){
                    if(maccountCount .containsKey(e.WhatId)){
                        AccountCount = maccountCount.get(e.WhatId);
                    }
                    AccountCount = AccountCount + 1;
                    maccountCount.put(e.whatid,AccountCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(trigger.isdelete){
        for(event e: trigger.old){
            if(e.whoId != null){
                if(string.valueOf(e.WhoId).left(3) == '003'){
                    if(mcontactCount.containsKey(e.WhoId)){
                        ContactCount = mcontactCount.get(e.WhoId);
                    }
                    ContactCount = ContactCount - 1;
                    mcontactCount.put(e.whoid,ContactCount);
                }
            }
            if(e.whatId != null){
                if(string.valueOf(e.WhatId).left(3) == '006'){
                    if(mopportunityCount.containsKey(e.WhatId)){
                        OptyCount = mopportunityCount.get(e.WhatId);
                    }
                    OptyCount = OptyCount - 1;
                    mopportunityCount.put(e.whatid,OptyCount);
                }
                if(string.valueOf(e.WhatId).left(3) == '001'){
                    if(maccountCount.containsKey(e.WhatId)){
                        AccountCount = maccountCount.get(e.WhatId);
                    }
                    AccountCount = AccountCount - 1;
                    maccountCount.put(e.whatid,AccountCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(mcontactCount.keyset().size()>0){
        list<contact> contactToUpdate = new list<contact>([SELECT id,Count_of_Activity__c FROM contact WHERE Id IN :mcontactCount.keyset()]); for(contact o: contactToUpdate){
            o.Count_of_Activity__c = o.Count_of_Activity__c + mcontactCount.get(o.id);
        }
        if(contactToUpdate.size()>0){
            update contactToUpdate;
        }
    }
    if(mopportunityCount.keyset().size()>0){
        list<opportunity> opportunityToUpdate = new list<opportunity>([SELECT id,Count_of_Activity__c FROM opportunity WHERE Id IN :mopportunityCount.keyset()]); for(opportunity o: opportunityToUpdate){
            o.Count_of_Activity__c = o.Count_of_Activity__c + mopportunityCount.get(o.id);
        }
        if(opportunityToUpdate.size()>0){
            update opportunityToUpdate;
        }
    }
    if(maccountCount.keyset().size()>0){
        list<account> accountToUpdate = new list<account>([SELECT id,Count_of_Activity__c FROM account WHERE Id IN :maccountCount.keyset()]);
        for(account a: accountToUpdate){
            a.Count_of_Activity__c = a.Count_of_Activity__c + maccountCount.get(a.id);
        }
        if(accountToUpdate.size()>0){
            update accountToUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

I am need of trigger handler. TO many Soql queries hits the limits or some one suggest me the test class of this trigger.

Comment: I am trying to write down the test but getting errors.

Comment: Dont put additional information into comments. Edit the question instead. And mentioning "that you are getting errors" doesn't help. Please check the help center to understand how you should rework your question.